# Django form is adding characters when I am editing details

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

Here is how my form is set up (all the fields are the same):

```
class AddColourForm(forms.Form):

    colour = forms.CharField(
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        max_length=100,
        required=False,
        label = "Colour:",
    )
```

Here is my view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    selected_colour.code = form.cleaned_data['code'],
    selected_colour.name = form.cleaned_data['colour'],
    selected_colour.save()
```

Here is what happens when it goes into the db:

> (u'red',) (u'#ff0000',)

I have tried adding `unicode()` wrappers around the cleaned data before saving but that isn't working.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you want a 24-bit unsigned value, not a string for u'#ff0000'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the commas after each line like so (they aren't necessary):

```
selected_colour.code = form.cleaned_data['code']
selected_colour.name = form.cleaned_data['colour']
selected_colour.save()
```

it looks like the commas are turning your data into a list.

Comment: apart from being necessary, @drew2 is saving a tuple string representation in the db.

Comment: Yes! This has worked straight away. It's my own fault from copying the code to add a new colour to the db and then altering it. I will remember this in future. Thanks!!!!!